# How can I enable USB tethering on an Android 4.0 device with my application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How I can Enable Usb Tethering programatically on 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049547/how-i-can-enable-usb-tethering-programatically-on-4-0)

How can I enable USB tethering on an Android 4.0 device with my application?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913645/android-enable-usb-tethering-programatically-there-is-an-app-that-did-it-for

Answer (score 0):

you can call a intent depending on your requirement...
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));...
which takes you to the usb settings page

Comment: but i wanna enable tethering from my app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10898921/1466009   this link may help you...but i am not sure if it is applicable in ics4.0

Comment: i think you cannot enable USB tethering directly.User has to do it