# Android enable Usb Tethering programatically in AOSP

Tags: android, tethering

I am developing Android application. I need to enable Usb tethering programatically when Usb is connected. Due to android security i am not able to do it in 4.4 version. So i downloaded android 4.4 source code to make some changes on it.can anyone guide me how to do it?

Comment: Guy, try to do like this post. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913645/android-enable-usb-tethering-programmatically-there-is-an-app-that-did-it-fo

Comment: It works only in 2.3 and it does not work above 4.0

Answer (score 0):

the code below can work well in 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, version ,but can't work well in 4.3 and 4.4 version

```
try {  


            Class<?> classBluetoothPan = Class.forName(sClassName);

            Constructor<?> ctor = classBluetoothPan.getDeclaredConstructor(Context.class, BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.class);
            ctor.setAccessible(true);
            //Object instance = ctor.newInstance(getApplicationContext(), new BTPanServiceListener(getApplicationContext()));                 
            Object instance = ctor.newInstance(this, new BTPanServiceListener(this));
            //  Set Tethering ON
            Class[] paramSet = new Class[1];
            paramSet[0] = boolean.class;

            Method setTetheringOn = classBluetoothPan.getMethod("setBluetoothTethering", paramSet);
            //Method setTetheringOn = classBluetoothPan.getDeclaredMethod("setBluetoothTethering", paramSet);

            setTetheringOn.invoke(instance,true);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```