# Programmatically enable USB Tethering in Single-Use Android App with Device Owner permissions?

Tags: java, android, tethering, device-owner

I need to be able to enable USB tethering automatically when the device boots in 
a single-use, device owner Android application. I was unable to find anything on Google that shows that it is possible without rooting. However, I was wondering since we have device owner permissions, if there is something we can do to enable it? I am targeting Android 7.0+.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use the onBoot broadcast receiver with the code in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913645/android-enable-usb-tethering-programmatically-there-is-an-app-that-did-it-fo

Comment: @jrschlump where you able to solve this?

Comment: @AbhasTandon No, we moved to using Knox SDK instead of using Device Owner. With Knox SDK, you can enable USB tethering.