# How can I achieve USB tethering/debugging enabling programmatically?

Tags: android, debugging, usb, tethering

I want to programatically enable the USB tethering,USB debugging in android.Is it possible.What are the system permissions to be declared in manifest file.Can someone please help me out in the coding???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - enable USB tethering programmatically - there is an app that did it for 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913645/android-enable-usb-tethering-programmatically-there-is-an-app-that-did-it-fo)

Answer (score 0):

This code enables USB **tethering**

```
    public void enableTethering() {

                    Object conService= getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    for (Method m : obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {

                        if (m.getName().equals("tether")) {
                            try {
                                m.invoke(conService, "usb0");
                            } catch (IllegalArgumentException |  
                                 IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException   e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
            }
```

Comment: I hope its will helps you

Comment: does this require phone to be rooted ??or will it work on any android os?

Comment: Is it possible without rooting the phone?

Comment: In home Screen Activity oncreate() method  call enableTethering() method

Comment: I checked rooted mobile its works fine,I did n't check unrooted mobile.If you have unrooted please test this code i hope it will work. other wise you need rooted mobile for this code